# "Best" linear approximation for $1/(1+x)$

Tags: optimization, power-series

We all know that $1/(1+x)$ can be approximated by $\sum (-x)^n$, but the series converges quite slowly. So I started to look at the general series $\sum a_n x^n$, With an attempt to minimize the maximal difference between the fraction and the series, i.e:

For given $n$, Find
$$a_1,a_2,\ ...\ a_n\ $$
Such that: $$\Delta = max \left|\frac{1}{1+x} - \sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i\right|,\ x\in[0,1)$$
Is minimal.

- Is there a general solution for this problem?
- If not, is there at least an analytical solution For $n=1,2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is called the polynomial of best uniform approximation, sometimes referred to as the Chebyshev or minimax approximation. It can be computed using [Remes algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remez_algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

For any finite $n$ there is a analytic solution as you have a continuous differentiable (with 
finite exceptions) function on a compact set. (if you look at $x\in [0,1]$). My first idea would be orthogonal projection, but as $\max$ is not induced by a skalarproduct that won't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help me find the actual coefficients.

Comment: taylor series in $x=1/2$ would be a way to get good coefficients, with not so many work, but there should be better